# How to calculate fee xcm message at source chain and destination chain?

Tags: xcm, xcmp, fee

I am looking for a way to charge for xcm message.

(I know this topic has been discussed a lot, but I still haven't found my own answer, and haven't written a script to test, so I want to open this discussion further ^.^).
As far as I know, charging for xcm messages has two steps.

Step 1: Calculate the total weight for all instructions that xcm uses. Here is the formula I found:

```rust
weight = base_weight + (num_assets * weight_per_asset) + (asset_id.len() * weight_per_byte)
```

Step 2: Calculate fee from the weight given in step 1.
I found the following code:

```rust
pub fn estimate_fee_for_weight(weight: Weight) -> u128 {
let (_, units_per_second, units_per_mb) = TokensPerSecondPerMegabyte::get();

units_per_second * (weight.ref_time() as u128) / (WEIGHT_REF_TIME_PER_SECOND as u128)
units_per_mb * (weight.proof_size() as u128) / (WEIGHT_PROOF_SIZE_PER_MB as u128)
}
```

So let me ask:

1. How is the value of `unit_per_second` and `units_per_mb` calculated?
2. It seems that Weight is the common unit of all tokens (Dot, Kusama, Moonbeam, ...) so with different tokens, how to convert weight to a token like it? That is, how will `weight to dot` differ from `weight to KSM`? How to calculate?
3. How to determine the weight limit in xcm?
4. How can I find the base_weight of all instructions?

Thank you for your help.
Some reference I found: https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-docs.git

Answer (score 0):

1. How is the value of unit_per_second and units_per_mb calculated?

The functions you are using are a implementation for the XCM Docs example, in this case the `unit_per_second` and `units_per_mb` 1_000_000_000_000 and 1024 * 1024, and they are are specified in the code (see [link](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-docs/blob/main/examples/src/simple_test_net/relay_chain.rs#L169C2-L170C68)):

```rs
pub TokensPerSecondPerMegabyte: (AssetId, u128, u128) =
        (Concrete(TokenLocation::get()), 1_000_000_000_000, 1024 * 1024);
```

2. It seems that Weight is the common unit of all tokens (Dot, Kusama, Moonbeam, ...) so with different tokens, how to convert weight to a token like it? That is, how will weight to dot differ from weight to KSM? How to calculate?

A configuration item in the Executor Config: `Trader`, is the responsible to convert the required weight units into fees

3. How to determine the weight limit in xcm?

By using `WeightLimit::Limited()`, you guarantee the message will error if it tries to use more weight than you expect, if you don't mind this, you can use `WeightLimit::Unlimited`.

4. How can I find the base_weight of all instructions?

For example Polkadot currently uses a fixed amount of weight for all XCM instructions, which is 1,000,000,000 weight units per instruction. Is defined in the config (See link to the [code](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/polkadot/runtime/polkadot/src/xcm_config.rs#L111)).
In the XCM docs example you are looking this is a bit less, 1,000(See [code](https://github.com/paritytech/xcm-docs/blob/main/examples/src/simple_test_net/relay_chain.rs#L168)).